# ASP.NETC# Why is app_offline.htm file created automatically in solution?

Tags: asp.net, app-offline.htm

I'm new to ASP.NET,

From the beginning, I am seeing that a file app_offline.htm is created automatically in my Project(in Solution Explorer) and the project stops working, when I run/debug, a page loads and say that I have to delete the app_offline.htm file to run my project.
My teacher say that I should delete it whenever it gets created, and she doesn't know why it is created.I looked up in internet and all I could find that many people have problems with app_offline.htm  while uploading he site. I'm not uploading or anything, so, why does this thing  creates automatically?
Does it create any problem in future?